# Why my logo is displaying in menu bar?

Tags: html, css

Please check the code below.

My image is not displaying over menu-bar. (Using css after a long time :))

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation-container">
            <div class="rectangle">
                <div class="logo"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1050px;
}

.rectangle {
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    height: 62px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top:0em;
}

.logo {
    background:url('company_logo.png');
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have used `#logo` instead of `.logo`

Comment: Even if I use '.logo', it is still not working.

Comment: You can't just close a div like that (.logo). Close it with an end tag '</div>'.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a height and width for your `.logo`. [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymcSU/1/).

Note that `<div>` cannot be self-closed, you must have a `</div>`. `<div/>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: Or they should just use `<img />`.

Comment: @sainirahul If it worked for you, click the tick mark to the left of the questions, you'll get reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

id = #
class = .

You need to update your css so that it says `.logo`, not `#logo`.

Also your HTML should be `<div class="logo"></div>`.

Also, as you have not specified the height of .logo this will not work, I recommend you change it to:
`<div class="rectangle logo"></div>`